# How to declare a property with a dependency of other property in state constructor of React?

Tags: reactjs, constructor, dependencies, state

I'm trying to create a class with some properties the second depends on the value of the first, but I want to initialize them.
So this want I'm trying I just include ... in this example to simulate my component call.

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
  Section:sectionsData.filter(function(section){return section.id=="id"}),
  questions : this.state.Section[0].questions.map(...)
}
```

I'm getting "Cannot read property 'Section' of undefined"

I've already tried to use the section value just as a member of the class like this

```
this.Section[0]
```

But also did not work.

And how can I update the value of those properties using  this.setState()

Answer (score 1):

`this.state` is not set yet. Use this :

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    const sections = sectionsData.filter(function(section){return section.id=="id"});
    this.state={
       Section: sections,
       questions : sections[0].questions.map(...)
    }
}
```

You probably want to check the length of sections as well.

Comment: Other question if I cannot do the set in the same block do I net to do the same thing to change the state using this.setState(), like use one function for update Section and then call other for to set questions? @Mohamed Ramrami